# How to retrieve value of n-th element in pandas Series object?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a series object (1 column of a `DataFrame`) and would like to extract the value of the first element. Is there a way to do this simply without converting to a list and without knowing the key? Or is the only way to access it by converting it to a list first using `tolist()[n]`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print df
  col
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e

print df.iloc[0]
col    a
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! When I was looking around the web I found the `iloc()` function, which returns an indexer, but not the value. Using `iloc[n]` with the square brackets works. No need for the `.values`.